# Setting the year in Calendar

Tags: java

I have the following piece of code.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
Date start = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(start));
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
Date end = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(end));
```

It prints:

```
31/12/2016 22:00
01/01/2016 05:00
```

I expect that the year of the second date is 2017. What is going on? I'm using Java 1.7.

Comment: What is your `dateFormat` ?

Comment: I got `31-12-2016 22:00` and `01-01-2017 05:00`

Comment: I just ran your code and it seems fine, printed 2017, no problem. Can you update you code with the full version ? maybe something outside that can be influencing ? like thread ?

Comment: Updated the question with the used format.

Comment: Why do people keep using `YYYY` instead of `yyyy` without knowing what `YYYY` does? Unbelievable. In other words: starting using a proper pattern for printing your date.

Comment: @Tom Because I didn't realise that was an option. Thanks to your very helpful comment, I went on to read the docs and I know understand my error. So thanks, I guess.

Comment: Auberon, it is *always* important to read the documentation, especially when passing "stuff" into the a constructor or a method. Please remember that for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct date format should be `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`, not `dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm`, note the lower case `y`.

With that it works correctly.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> y Year
>   Y Week year

Explanation of the difference between year and week year (from [here](https://coderanch.com/t/619912/certification/Difference-Year-Week-year-SimpleDateFormat)):

> A week year is a year where all the weeks in the year are whole weeks.
>   [...] Basically, this guarantees that a program working on a week's
>   data will not transition between years. [...] this also means that the beginning of the year may not start on the first of January.

Comment: This works. Thank you. From reading the docs, I couldn't understand what a "Week year" is. Do you care to elaborate?

Comment: @Auberon added explanation

Answer (score -1):

This is working fine with the following dataFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
```

Comment: it's up to you. how you will take your date format pattern. i simply given an example, because you didn't mentioned the data format in your question. please have common sense.